# Call C++ function inside VS watch or immediate window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, watch, immediate-window

Question is fairly simple: Is there a way to call a **C++ function** from **watch** window of **visual studio**, when that function is declared in **File1.hpp**, defined in File1.cpp and the **debugger** is currently stopped with a breakpoint in AnotherFile.cpp?

**File1.hpp**

```
int &getValue();
```

**File1.cpp**

```
int &getValue()
{
    static int value = 0;
    return value;
}
```

**AnotherFile.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0; //Debugger is stopped here, and in watch window of VS i want to call getValue() of 
               //File1.hpp, to check the result
}
```

This example is simplified.
When I call getValue() and the debugger is stopped in **File1.cpp**, the value is shown in watch window of Visual Studio correctly.
When I call getValue() and debugger is stopped in **AnotherFile.cpp**. I get *identifier getValue(void) is undefined*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you could use `Immediate` in `Debug->Windows->Immediate`.
[image]

Then, when you debug `int x=0`, you could input `getValue()` in `Immediate Window`. And you will see the console output `value 0`.

[image]